# Decoupling UI components in React

Tags: javascript, redux, reactjs, react-redux

I am new to React but have not found a suitable solution to my first problem on the job.

The specific context is of a navigation component that composes several other components and together they are a redistributable unit, independently testable as a whole module.

The use case of the component is to sometimes render it in desktop mode using React media queries, and other times in mobile - in which case it needs decorated with flyout behaviour.

So I want to decouple the navigation component from having to know about flyout.  In respect of the 'tell don't ask' principle or event driven I want to be able to notify a parent that navigation has changed and depending on how this component is implemented respond accordingly (in mobile, the flyout needs to get hidden, in desktop there is no flyout decorator).

I looked at redux-ui which is a nice syntactic sugar using annotations but falls down when a property it is trying to set in the state hierarchy doesn't exist.  And besides, this breaks the decoupling model.

I am a little abstract here I realise but does anyone have a recommendation on how I might approach this?  I suspect that a possible solution might involve not having a hierarchy (is-a) imposed by the decorating wrapper and rather has-a flyout capability but would welcome industry experience on this.

Thanks

Comment: With vanilla React, to communicate changes back up to the parent you generally pass a callback from the parent to the child as a prop and call it from the child when appropriate.  Does this not work in your case?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to handle this. The simplest would be to do it purely in CSS. Have all the HTML for the component always in the component and only the CSS would know about mobile or not.

Alternatively, you could have a piece of global state that gets set when the app loads and tells the app whether it's on mobile or desktop, and then pass that down to any relevant components. This method would be a bit of a pain because 'mobile' and 'desktop' are really just 'small screen' and 'larger screen' and as a result, this may change while the user is in the middle of using the app (like changing screen size, for example). So you'd have to keep track of all that with a bunch of listeners that are constantly listening for window resize events.

The simplest solution does seem to be pure CSS here.

Comment: I guess ultimately the handler on some parent would eventually be handling some CSS but also there is a modification of the app behaviour.  So I am looking for how to decouple my component from the implementation.  In a traditional architecture I would use events.  What I am finding with React is that handlers between components bind them explicitly but how do I communicate state change beyond that?

Comment: Can you just add a prop to your nav that sets it to `mobile` or `desktop` and have internal logic inside the nav component that changes based on that prop?